# HQL case when error

Tags: java, sql, hql

I have the following query:

```
FROM Tbloans WHERE paidamt - (case when due=lastdue then dueamt else dueamt+nxtduedt end)>1
```

It gives me an error like this:

> expecting "`end`", found '`+`' Unexpected token: end

Sorry my pc cannot access Internet so I'm using a phone. Can't paste the whole error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use `case` in the `where` clause. It is just boolean logic

```
WHERE (due =  lastdue and paidamt - dueamt > 1)
   OR (due <> lastdue and paidamt - (dueamt + nxtduedt) > 1)
```

Comment: Thanks. It gave me the result I want. My query works in SQL though. Do you know why it's not working in HQL?

Comment: No, sorry I am no HQL expert